# Vector Force Application

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, physics

I have this question for Math StackExchange Site.

Suppose you would like to cros a $132 ft$ -wide river in a motor boat. Assume that the motorboat can travel at $7.0mph$ relative to the water and that the current is flowing west at the rate of $3.0mph$. The bearing $\Theta$ is chosen so that the motor boat will land at a point exactly across from the starting point. (Hint : 1mile = 5280 feet).

Given Diagram:

[image]

A) At what seed will the motor boat be traveling relative to the banks?

B) How long will it take for the motorboat to make the crossing?

c) What is the measure of the angle $\Theta$

So ofcourse i tried to do all of them:

A)

Since In My Oppinon i i thought it was a right triangle i did:
\begin{align}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \\
& a^2 = c^2 - b^2  \\ 
 & a = 6.32 mph \\
\end{align}

B)
I Have No Clue Whatsoever how to do this one...

c)
\begin{align}
sin(\Theta) = \frac{3mph}{7mph}  \\
& \Theta = 25.37 ^\circ  \\ 
\end{align}

Ok So my question here is how in the world do you do B. And did i messup anywhere? Thanks a lot, this site is by far the best math community site ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displacement of the boat is the product of its velocity and the time it travels.
$$d = vt$$
You found the velocity of the boat in miles per hour in part (a).  We know that the displacement is $132~\text{ft}$.  How many miles is that?  Solve for $t$.

Comment: Thanks N.F As usual, but physics in math class? i mean sure i have a phyiscs class, but we never learned physics in math class.. are you sure this is the only way to solve it? And did i correctly calculate the other "calculations" (Congratz on 15k)

Comment: Yes, your calculations are correct for parts (a) and (c).  There may be other ways to solve part (b), but this seems to be the simplest.  Let's not forget that entire branches of mathematics such as calculus were invented precisely to do physics, so it is not surprising that applications to physics arise in your mathematics class.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok thankyou Mr Taussig. Thanks a lot!